# How to return something from the database using sequelize in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, select, sequelize.js

I'm using a very simple server in express and I want to return everything from a table callend "contas".

When I use bash, the query `SELECT "user_id", "username", "password" FROM "contas" AS "Conta";` returns a row.

But it seems like the same query produces an error. Here's a bit of the error:

```
Erro:  Error
    at Query.run (C:\Users\mecha\elearning\backEnd\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\postgres\query.js:50:25)      
    at C:\Users\mecha\elearning\backEnd\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:315:28
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async PostgresQueryInterface.select (C:\Users\mecha\elearning\backEnd\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-interface.js:407:12)
    at async Function.findAll (C:\Users\mecha\elearning\backEnd\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1140:21)
    at async getAllContas (file:///C:/Users/mecha/elearning/backEnd/models.js:33:27) {
  name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
  parent: error: relation "contas" does not exist
      at Parser.parseErrorMessage (C:\Users\mecha\elearning\backEnd\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:287:98)  
      at Parser.handlePacket (C:\Users\mecha\elearning\backEnd\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:126:29)       
      at Parser.parse (C:\Users\mecha\elearning\backEnd\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:39:38)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mecha\elearning\backEnd\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\index.js:11:42)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
      at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
      at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
      at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
    length: 105,
    severity: 'ERROR',
    code: '42P01',
    detail: undefined,
    hint: undefined,
    position: '47',
    internalPosition: undefined,
    internalQuery: undefined,
    where: undefined,
    schema: undefined,
    table: undefined,
    column: undefined,
    dataType: undefined,
    constraint: undefined,
    file: 'parse_relation.c',
    line: '1395',
    routine: 'parserOpenTable',
    sql: 'SELECT "user_id", "username", "password" FROM "contas" AS "Conta";',
    parameters: undefined
  }
```

Here's a bit of code

```
//server.js
import express from 'express';
import sequelize from './db_connect.js';
import { getAllContas } from './models.js';

sequelize.authenticate()
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
        return getAllContas()
 })
    .then((allContas => {console.log(allContas)} ))
    .catch(error => {console.log("erro: ", error)});


const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello world!");
});

app.listen(3000);
```

```
//db_connect.js
import {Sequelize} from 'sequelize';

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    'devtest',
    'postgres',
    'a',
    {
        host: 'localhost',
        dialect: 'postgres'
    }
);

export default sequelize;
```

```
//models.js
import { Sequelize, DataTypes, Model } from 'sequelize';
import sequelize from './db_connect.js';

class Conta extends Model {}

Conta.init({
  // Model attributes are defined here
  user_id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },
  username: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
    // allowNull defaults to true
  }
}, {
  // Other model options go here
  sequelize, // We need to pass the connection instance
  modelName: 'Conta', // We need to choose the model name
  tableName: 'contas',
  timestamps: false
});

export async function getAllContas() {
    try {
        const allContas = await Conta.findAll();
        return allContas;
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log("Erro: ", error);
        throw error;
    }
}
```

I don't know if it is necessary, but here is the code I used to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE contas (user_id serial PRIMARY KEY, username VARCHAR ( 50 ) UNIQUE NOT NULL, password VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL);`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check if you connect to the correct DB

Answer (score 0):

First Please check you are connecting to the correct database.
If the db credentials are correct and the connection is working fine check if the table exists in the database using the list command in postgres interface (shell or any applications).
If the table does not exist in the database generate a sequelize migration file to migrate the table to the potstgres db.
You can get more details from the sequelize [migration](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/migrations/) documentation.